# WebView поддержка Flash Player

Tags: android, flash, webview

Здравствуйте,у меня проект для *Android 2.2* ,нужно чтобы мой браузер(*WebView*) поддерживал *Flash Player* ,он нужен для проигрование музыки на мобильном сайте.

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
myebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Везде говорят что нужно использовать метод *setPluginState* ,но все равно браузер не поддерживает Flash .Как можно исправить ситуацию?

*setPluginsEnabled(true)* уже устарел и рекомендуется использовать *setPluginState()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идеи, нужно чтобы на девайсе был установлен FlashPlayer.

Comment: Я это проверю,а так дополнительного кода не нужно?

Comment: и это тоже проверишь...

Comment: по идеи не нужно

Comment: всё работает.